# Part of the text should change in Carousel using pure html css no JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, aurelia

I have a Carousel where part of the text should change at a fixed interval. need to change the text from WEB to mobile IoT application development transport products etc
I'm using aurelia framework

https://www.codeply.com/p/7k0uDOyaf3

```js
$('#carouselExampleSlidesOnly').carousel({
  interval: 500
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://worldtransfer.online/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/worldmap-bg.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption big clearfix p-5" style="width:fit-content">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <h1 class="text-uppercase text-white">We Architect,</h1>
          <h3 class="pt-2 pl-2">Design and Develop</h3>
        </div>
        <h1 class="text-uppercase"><span class="text-warning pr-3">Web</span>Application</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"><img class="d-block w-75 image-left" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/145335/file-407477601-gif/blog-files/the-importance-of-mobile-responsive-web-design.gif" alt="system Image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can yor provide your current and expected behaviour

Comment: Currently, it is just static text nothing is happening no slides changes nothing, I want the text part WEB to be changed nothing else no background no other text.

Comment: because your jQuery script is not in the begining, move your `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>` to top

Answer (score 2):

Move your jQuery script to top of all scrips, check the snippet

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$('#carouselExampleSlidesOnly').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
```

```css
.carousel-inner {
  background-image: url("https://worldtransfer.online/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/worldmap-bg.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 250px
}

.carousel-caption {
  top: 1em;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative
}

.d_flex {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height:100%;
  top:100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="d_flex d-flex">
    <h2 class="text-uppercase text-white">We Architect,</h2>
    <h3 class="text-white">Design and Develop</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="carousel-caption" >
        <div class="carousel-text">
          <h1 class="text-uppercase">
            <span class="text-warning pr-3">Web</span>Application
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="carousel-text">
          <h1 class="text-uppercase">
            <span class="text-warning pr-3">Mobile</span>Application
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption" >
        <div class="carousel-text">
          <h1 class="text-uppercase">
            <span class="text-warning pr-3">Desktop</span>Application
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Write now all the slide moves with the background but I just want the text WEB to change with other texts

Comment: You mean you want static background, and the text should show carousel property, right ?

Comment: Yes, but not all text, only one word.

Comment: @NewBie_WannaBe can you give more details

Comment: As you can see the Carousel has two images one as background and another at the forefront with left align and text right align in the same text on the second line we have a word WEB I want that text to be replaced by architecture and some other 7 words.

Comment: @NewBie_WannaBe are you looking for this kind, check the updated snippet. If its not what you want , please provide a detailed image

Comment: Yes, but instead of the complete slide only one word changes.

Comment: https://codepen.io/thiagoteles/pen/ogoxLw 

here the whole line is being typed I want just a part of text example animate to be replaced by some other text after 5 second

Comment: Again the snippet slides the whole second line instead just change the text WEB not application it should not slide it should have a fadeIn effect

Comment: @NewBie_WannaBe I think this is a kind of home work, You have to so something to get the desired answer. why dont you make a try here after ??

Comment: No, I just wanna try that out.